# Solr or Nhibernate Search

Tags: lucene, solr, nhibernate.search, solrnet

Bit confused here,

How’s [Solr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solr) or [Solrnet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) any different from [Nhibernate Search](http://darioquintana.com.ar/blogging/2007/12/09/nhibernate-search/)? Does Solr offer anything more to [Lucene.net](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html) that [Nhibernate Search](http://darioquintana.com.ar/blogging/2007/12/09/nhibernate-search/)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I explained the differences and relationships between these projects in [this blog post](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2009/10/untangling-mess-solr-solrnet-nhibernate.html).

In a nutshell: while Lucene(.net) is a library, Solr is a stand-alone Java application that uses Lucene to provide full-text indexing and searching through a XML/HTTP interface. This means that it can be used from any platform/language. While very flexible, it's easier to use than raw Lucene and provides features commonly used in search applications, like [faceted search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview) and [hit highlighting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters). It also handles [caching](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching), [replication](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2009/05/31/solr-index-replication/), [sharding](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch), and has a nice web admin interface. None of those features are directly provided by Lucene.net / NHibernate.Search.

SolrNet is a client to communicate with Solr from a .net application.